# Como enviar só uma planilha por email em VBA e não o arquivo todo usando o código abaixo

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, email

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Public Const C_Title  As String = "ef3.Cinco"
'Metodos
Public Sub SendMail(obj As MailClass) 'Nome da classe...

    Dim appOutLook As Outlook.Application '"Importando" Outlook
    Set appOutLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim MailOutLook As Outlook.MailItem 'Propriedades de mensagem
    Set MailOutLook = appOutLook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With MailOutLook
        .To = obj.Destinatario 'Destinatários (separados por ';')
        .Subject = obj.Assunto 'Assunto
        .Body = obj.Detalhe 'Corpo do eMail
        .Attachments.Add (obj.Anexo) 'Caminho do anexo
        .Send 'Enviar
    End With
    Set MailOutLook = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Vou enviar o código, mas, basicamente se copiar a planilha com a aba que deseja enviar e anexar esse arquivo fica mais fácil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideal seria salvar em um novo arquivo a planilha que deseja enviar e passar o caminho completo como parâmetro para essa função, segue exemplo genérico que fiz como modelo:

```
Sub enviaPlanilhaAtiva()

Dim oOutlook As Object
Dim oEmail As Object
Dim wbAtual As Workbook
Dim sNomeArquivo As String
Dim sLocalTemp As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set oOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oEmail = oOutlook.CreateItem(0)
sLocalTemp = "C:\temp\"

' Copia a planilha ativa e salva em local temporário
ActiveSheet.Copy
Set wbAtual = ActiveWorkbook

' Aqui você define qual planilha deve ser gravada
sNomeArquivo = wbAtual.Worksheets(1).Name

On Error Resume Next
Kill sLocalTemp & sNomeArquivo
On Error GoTo 0
wbAtual.SaveAs FileName:=sLocalTemp & sNomeArquivo

With oEmail
    '.To = "destino@gmail.com"
    '.Subject = "Assunto"
    '.body = "Corpo do e-mail"
    .Attachments.Add wbAtual.FullName
    .Display
End With

'Deleta o arquivo temporário
wbAtual.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly
Kill wbAtual.FullName
wbAtual.Close SaveChanges:=False

Set oEmail = Nothing
Set oOutlook = Nothing
End Sub
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: muito obrigado amigo. Deu certo. Grato. Você nao saberia me dizer coo fazer pra minhas macros nao usarem tanto processamento né? Pq eu tenho essa planilha e cada vez q uso uma macro ela trava, qnd o arquivo ta aberto ele ocupa 1.6GB na Ram e o tamanho ta de 350mb e cada vez q salva ele aumenta, sendo q eu sou atualizo dados, não chego a acrescentar.

Comment: @alexandre teria de ver o código para melhorar alguns pontos de utilização de memória, liberação de variáveis, divisão do código com funções muito longas em novas funções, mas pelo que vi, já utiliza classes e imagino que teria de garimpar para ver qual classe está tomando muito a memória, mas teria de debugar o código e ver ponto a ponto o que pode estar aumentando a memória. Se conseguir avaliar a função que está ocasionando esse uso excessivo de memória poste na pergunta que fez sobre isso para vermos e tento ver se posso ajudar. Abs!

Comment: @alexandre no caso do salvar e aumentar o tamanho da planilha, preciso perguntar qual versão do office está usando, pois a partir do 2007 o Office trabalha bem a memória e tamanho dos arquivos, mas toda vez que salva (com o arquivo aberto) ele utiliza alguns espaços a mais para garantir edições futuras e salvar rascunhos, ao fechar a planilha esses espaços são esvaziados. Espero ter contribuído com algo a mais. Abs

Comment: Então amigo, eu não posso postar aqui porque o código tem segurança, eh da empresa que trabalho. Porem eu uso a versão 2013, e chega uma hora que o programa fica tão pesado que ele não abre mais o VBE. Diz que a memória é insuficiente.

Comment: @alexandre no 2013 teoricamente deveria ter melhor desempenho do que os outros, se no 2013 está ocasionando isso, provável que precisa garimpar seu código de alguma maneira. Tente rever seus loops e variáveis, procure usar mais WITH ao invés de configurar automático isso ajuda na otimização de memória e desempenho. Se pudesse, gostaria de ajudar a solucionar essa questão. Abs

Comment: Evert, muito obrigado pela sua ajuda, foi de extrema importancia para meu projeto, eu consegui otimiza-lo e agora esta uma beleza, rápido. Muito obrigado mesmo pela ajuda. E creio que não será a ultima, pois eu estou aprendi VBA na quarta passada, então terei muito que ver pela frente. Mesmo assim muito obrigado.